# How to convert char to string in C#

Tags: c#

I want convert char to string,How can I do?

```
char[] buf;
Int32 dwsize;
buf = new char[256];
dwsize = 256;
if (Pxx_ATE.GetProjectName(DeviceId, decimal.ToInt32(up_ProIndex.Value), buf, dwsize))
{
  textBox_projName.Text = buf; //Here error,I want convert buf to string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
textBox_projName.Text = buf;
```

with

```
textBox_projName.Text = new string(buf);
```

Comment: I tested, it's ok: char[] buf = new char[256];
 buf = "demo".ToCharArray();
  textBox_projName.Text = new string(buf);